# MIPS String Storage

Tags: c, arrays, string, assembly, mips

So in MIPS we can allocate space for strings in the `.data` section of our program. However, this only works for predefined string variables. Let us say somebody calls a function instead somewhere in our code like this:

```
myFunc("blablabla");
```

To do this in MIPS we need to store `blablabla` in memory. How would we allocate memory to store `blablabla` in the `.text` segment of our program, rather than in `.data`?

Comment: _"How would we allocate memory to store blablabla in the .text segment of our program"_ That's no different from placing data in the `.data` section, except that you have to ensure that all instructions are word-aligned. But a compiler would probably place that string literal in one of the data sections.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

```
li      $v0, 9                  # Code in %v0: 9 -> Allocate heap memory 
li      $a0, 8                  # Allocate 8 bytes
syscall                         # System call for allocating space
```

You can allocate memory from the heap and store the string. You can change the 8 bytes i have used for example with the number of characters your string has. The question of how to count characters has already been answered.

After `syscall` the register $v0 holds the address of the allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some confusion. Your string constants need not be in the text section. They can be put into the data section just like other variables.

The function call at the end of the day just takes the address of the string (the label you will create in the data section).

You can reference this in the text section in the move instruction.